# What is this for a file name encoding and how to fix it?

Tags: linux, encoding, filenames, ms-dos, character-encoding

On my Linux machine I found old files (at least from 2004 if not older), so possibly Win9x days. Maybe they came over some old FAT drive on my disk or some old Samba share.

Umlaute are very weirdly encoded. Examples:

```
$ ls -la
insgesamt 1862
drwx------ 10 user users      11 Feb 15  2006  .
drwx------ 11 user users      11 Dez  2  2004  ..
-rw-------  1 user users 1796429 Apr 13  2004 'Geb'$'\344''udeplan.jpg'
drwx------  2 user users      17 Feb 15  2006 'K'$'\374''che'
```

The names should be Geb**ä**udeplan.jpg and K**ü**che.

This does not seem to be ISO-8859-15, ANSI or similar. Indeed, the hex values seem to be greater than 256.

I have tried multiple options with `convmv` and `detox` but nothing seems to fit.

I would like to scan my entire harddisk for similar files and fix them (to UTF8).

Comment: (You should be surprised if greater *or equal* 256.) The numbers are less than 256. In `$'\344'` the number is in octal. `\377` would be 255.

Comment: What *exactly* have you tried with `convmv` and `detox`? Please [edit] and be specific.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Good point, thanks! I think I forgot the `-r` flag. I used `convmv -f iso-8859-15 -t utf8 .` which only did the current directory node. So yes, it seems it is ISO-8859-15!

Comment: I thought of and successfully tested with `-f cp1250`. Anyway `convmv` is the tool.